# How to change field headers with VBA using data from the dataset?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access table that has generic headers.  In the table each column is populated with the number of parts ordered for a given day.  One column is populated with the beginning date.  This information changes weekly.  I would like the generic column names to be changed to a meaningful date name using the starting date in the field data.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Go ahead and post some of the code you have and have tried so we can better help :)

Answer (score 2):

Forget about chancing fields names - that will lead to endless troubles.

You could change the *Caption* of the field names, but that can also create a lot of confusion.

Best option is to use a query where you alias the field names. The SQL property of this is simple text you easily can manipulate:

```
Select Field1 As Something, Field2 As SomethingElse
From YourTable
```

That said …

> In the table each column is populated with the number of parts ordered
>   for a given day.

it sounds like you use the table as a spreadsheet.

That's a sure no-go, and you should read up on *how to normalize a database* - many guides are out there for the browsing.